# OSX : split Groovy script into multiple files

Tags: macos, groovy

On OSX, we can create an executable Groovy script as follows:

**File: SomeScript.groovy**

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy
println "Hello!!!!";
```

chmod +x ./SomeScript.groovy

How do I use the same approach, but split the cmd-line App up into multiple files? (As many Ruby cmd-line gems do).

I need quick light-weight, easy to modify scripting, at the same time as being able to split up my files into 10 or 20 classes.

Comment: I suppose that You need a dedicated location to place all the files there and main script will automatically resolve the dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create your separated logics in groovy classes (ex. Utils.groovy) with statics methods.

```
class Utils{
    static helloWorld(){
        println “hello world!"
    }
}
```

then in your script you can write

```
…mylogic…
helloWorld()
…mylogic…
```

Groovy will load automatically Utils.groovy class if it’s in the same dir of the script